# Checking when Enter key is pressed

Tags: jquery, keyup

I am trying to check for the event that the Enter key is executed with the value of an input containing something. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, I am running this on Google Chrome in the case that anyone is wondering.

```
$("#inputInput").on('keyup', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        if (document.getElementById("introInput").value != null) {
            var val = document.getElementById("introInput").value;
            alert("test");
        }
    } 
});
```

Anybody see what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Screwed up by misplacing the ID with an incorrect ID, leading to nowhere, explains why there were no errors printing.

Comment: `document.getElementById("introInput").value != null` The value cannot be `null` at any time. Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Would checking for "" be better? The console is not returning anything

Comment: Try only (document.getElementById("introInput").value)

Comment: That may work, however, the problem here seems to be the key as I have commented that out and used the alert as a test and nothing is alerted.

Comment: @Masterthias Yep, that would be better. Also I would suggest something like: `document.getElementById("introInput").value.trim().length === 0` - this is empty string.

Comment: @Masterthias If the alert is blocked, you will be getting an entry in the console.

Comment: Nevermind, I have got it working again. Thank you since you may have solved my problem for checking the value, however, it seems the problem was the fact that I was oblivious and had set the id to the wrong one. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.#inputInput', function(event) {
  var isEnter = (event.which == 13) ? true : false;
  if (isEnter) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Write your conditonals here
});
```

Comment: event.preventDefault() method stops the default action of an element from happening.